# Ember: this.get returns a getter (instead of the object I actually want)

Tags: jquery, object, asynchronous, ember.js, getter

I have an action which is supposed  to accept form input, grab the currently logged in user and save them together. When I try to get the logged in user via:

```
this.get('controllers.application.user')
```

I get:

```
Object { content: Getter, 3 more… }
```

Instead of:

```
{first_name: 'Ashton', X more...}
```

Weirdly getting a property of that object works fine, for example:

```
this.get('controllers.application.user.first_name')
```

Returns `'Ashton'`. Below is the context my code appears in, I'd appreciate any help you can offer.

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    needs: ['application'],
    actions: {
        createPost: function () {
            var writing = this.get('newContent');
            if (!writing.trim()) { return; }
            var post = this.store.createRecord('post', {
                writing: writing,
                author: this.get('controllers.application.user')
            });
            this.set('newContent', '');
            post.save();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Please post the code where the user is set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify that you want the content. Try this:

```
this.get('controllers.application.user.content')
```

When you do `this.get('controllers.application.user.first_name')` Ember knows to look inside the content for the first_name property, thus you get the property value returned.

Answer (score 2):

Is there any reason you are putting it into Ember Data?  It just seems like additional work for almost no gain (unless you plan on doing a lot of user editing etc).

From what I'm seeing it looks like you'd like the user to be accessible everywhere.  I'd recommend using the container to register the user on all of your controllers/routes.

```
App.initializer({
  name: "appUser",
  after:['ember-data'],

    initialize: function (container, application) {
      // if you want to use the store
      var store = container.lookup('store:main'),
          user = App.CoolUser.create();

      Ember.$.getJSON('api/users/me', function(data) {
        for(var key in data.user){
          user.set(key, data.user[key]);
        }
      });
      application.register("my:user", user, {instantiate:false});
      application.inject("controller", "user", "my:user");
      application.inject("route", "user", "my:user");
    }
});
```

And then from any controller/route you have direct access to your user using:

```
this.user....
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/711/edit

If it's important that the user is fetched before anything happens you will want to `deferReadiness` and `advanceReadiness` once the callback has occurred.  If you go this route you'll want to prepare for a failed callback as well so as to not leave your app in an stalled state.  http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Application.html#toc_routing

```
App = Ember.Application.create();
App.deferReadiness();
```

...

```
  Ember.$.getJSON('api/users/me', function(data) {
    for(var key in data.user){
      user.set(key, data.user[key]);
    }
    application.advanceReadiness();
  });
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/712/edit

Comment: I accepted Mathew's answer because it directly answered the question asked but your approach intrigues me: what would the possible implications be if I had many DS models and relationships between them, e.g. other users, friends, private messages, posts and comments? Would the user object play well with them?

Comment: if you plan on having a lot of related models it would be convenient to have it exist.  It's simple enough to still create the record in the initializer using the store.  http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/719/edit